# Site matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'pk': 3}

Tags: django

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs')


Installed Middleware:

('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/sampleapp/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  41.                                                                     **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  155.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
File "/var/www/sampleapp/allauth/account/views.py" in get_context_data
  67.                 "site": Site.objects.get_current(),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current
  26.             current_site = self.get(pk=sid)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/d
b/models/manager.py" in get
  143.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  401.                 (self.model._meta.object_name, kwargs))

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'pk': 3}
```

I am new to django,
Help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe in your settings, you set SITE_ID = 3?

Comment: in your `settings.py` file `SITE_ID` value should exist in the database. In your case it is set to 3 and it does not exist. So you might either want to create a new SITE object or change it to use an existing one.

Comment: Yes that iis the exact way, i fixed thi error.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem as well. I was going through the [PyCharm Django guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html). I fixed this by deleting my sqlite database file and running syncdb again. I don't know why it didn't work the first time, but it works now.

Also, it's probably worth downloading the [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) so that you can see the actual structure of your SQLite database. For this issue, you're interested in the django_site table. After I deleted my database file and reran syncdb, there was one row in this table.

Comment: Yes, deleting the db file and running `syncdb` worked for me as well. Still not sure why but it works.

Comment: I my case, I ran `syncdb` but while creating the tables there was an error and it crashed, then I ran `syncdb` again and when trying to login in the admin this error occurred. Finally, deleting the db and recreating it again from scratch fixed this problem. So I think this is because not all the tables were created.

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs because the first time that you executes `python manage.py syncdb.` isn't  specified a *main user*. To solve it, delete all tables created by django in data base (with mysql, postgresql..) or delete the database.db (with sqlite3), Then run `python manage.py syncdb` one more time