# Admin site is missing in django

Tags: django

When I try to GET /admin in my django project I get following error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/
Site matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'pk': 1}
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Site matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'pk': 1}
Exception Location: /Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 401
Python Executable:  /Users/me/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python
```

It is strange because in `settings.py` I do have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
...
)
```

I run project using `python manage.py runserver` and rest of my site is working except admin page... What might be a cause?

Comment: have you executed `syncdb`?

Comment: Have you change your Site model?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524176/site-matching-query-does-not-exist-lookup-parameters-were-pk-3

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the fact that you are using the "sites framework" but didn't "create" a site in your database.

`python manage.py syncdb`

and then add a site to `django_site` table with id=1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using the sites framework and it is still included in the settings.

**Just go to your settings.py file and comment the ''django.contrib.sites'(as shown below)**

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
**#'django.contrib.sites',**
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',p
'django.contrib.admin',
```

This should work now. **Also it will help if you upgrade your Django version to 1.6** (latest stable release). Just go to your command-line and type pip install django --upgrade to get the lastest Django stable version.